# Where does IP address information come from?

Tags: ip, analytics, ip-address

It appears that certain information is tied to an IP address, which is being taken advantage of by certain analytics packages such as [LeadForensics](http://www.leadforensics.com/) and [OpenTracker](http://www.opentracker.net/products/web-analytics/feature/company-identification) to identify anonymous visitors.

Where are companies like this getting information like this from?  Is it contained in a WHOIS lookup against the allocation body (ARIN, APNIC, RIPE) or something else?

The above tools are pretty accurate.

Comment: Are you referring to OpenTracker/etc. tracking user connection IPs? The IP that a user accesses a site from is "public" information, in that it is part of the connection established to a webserver.

Comment: I'm referring to the information attaining to the IP address, not what the IP address is.  OpenTracker etc tells me the name of the company that a visitor to my website is working for, for example.  To my knowledge this isn't in an IP address WHOIS.

Comment: From the looks of it, there's isn't an IP address WHOIS, because WHOIS will work on IP addresses. I tried my IP address (currently on a corporate internet), and it returned back my place of work. Try going to `who.is` and typing in an external IP for a company or something. Works on larger sites too, like YouTube's IP and whatnot.

Comment: It looks like the data comes from the ISP. The only data on my company is the company's name, and Quest, the internet provider for our company.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel I get that, but Lead Forensics, for example, know the company I work for based off my IP address.  I work for a company with <20 employees whose name is nowhere to be found on the IP WHOIS.

Comment: Oh ok, gotcha, on the same page now. Does your company have any public records based on their location? Maybe they are using the IP to figure out the location of your building, and cross-checking that with (Google Maps|Yellow Pages|etc.)?

Comment: Quickly looking through LeadForensics, OpenTracker, and Google Analytics, it looks like the way they accomplish this isn't public, and is probably proprietary and specific to their system, as both OpenTracker and LeadForensics note their company tracker as a specific feature.